# Are there flipped operators for Applicative?

Tags: haskell, applicative

The operators

```
$
. or <<<
<$>
<*>
=<<
<=<
```

Go very well together, each in some sense applying something on the left to something on the right. When thinking the other way, we have

```
&
>>>
>>=
>=>
```

But are there flipped versions of `<$>` and `<*>`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*lens* defines [`(<&>) = flip fmap`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.11/docs/Control-Lens-Lens.html#v:-60--38--62-). It will be available from [`Data.Functor` in *base*-4.11/GHC 8.4](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.4.1-rc1/docs/html/libraries/base-4.11.0.0/Data-Functor.html#v:-60--38--62-). `Control.Applicative` has [`(<**>)`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#v:-60--42--42--62-), which takes the arguments in the opposite order but is *not* `flip (<*>)` because effects are still sequenced from left to right.